# Why did it take over 100 years for Britain to begin seriously colonising America?

Tags: british-empire, colonization, colonial-america, colony

After the New World was discovered, it didn't take long for Spain, and relatively soon after, Portugal, to begin permanent colonisation there. It took over 100 years after the New World's discovery for other European powers, but particular to this question, Britain, to successfully attempt likewise, by which time many resource-rich regions were already claimed by Spain and Portugal. I'm aware they did perform expeditions to the New world, but didn't set up colonies there. Why was this? The vast quantities of goods Spain and Portugal were collecting must've been alluring. Was Britain uninterested in forming colonies in the New World/content with gaining power closer to home such as in Ireland, or were they simply unable to found new colonies?

Preliminary research wise, I couldn't find much on the actual reasons behind a lack of colonies for countries other than Spain and Portugal. I did find stuff on the expeditions of Britain in attempts to find the Northwest Passage and reach Asia, but nothing on why no colonies were otherwise formed in America. It seems to me that there would have been at least some economic incentive to colonise, but they didn't for a long time.

Comment: Might be useful to look at [Rakove's](https://politicalscience.stanford.edu/people/jack-rakove) analysis of the different colonization strategies.  Spain and Portugal were extractive; France & England were settling.  Different strategies  (easier to find him when I spell the name correctly.....)

Comment: France was largely extractive as well. Mostly their interest in continental North America was the fur trade, and let's not even get started on Haiti.

Comment: I suspect the answer for Britain may be different from the one for France. In which case, this will have to be broken up into two questions.

Comment: My main issue with this question is that people today use the word "colonization" to talk about several completely different things, and this question is taking full advantage of that modern ambiguity to make it look like there's something odd going on. Use terminology that differentiates conquest and rule of existing native cultures from building/transplanting settlements of your own culture with 0 regard for any existing native ones, and I'm not sure there'd still be any question here.

Comment: I've changed this question to specifically focus on Britain, I'll make a separate one for France later.

Comment: This answer might help, tl;dr they were busy at home https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/what-did-other-european-powers-say-when-portugal-and-spain-signed-the-treaty-of

Comment: @SPavel ah thank you very much, that question has pretty much all I was looking for. If only I'd seen it sooner I'd not have needed to make my own :p

Comment: It's not like nations had some deep scientific understanding of economics either, or a real idea of whether colonization would prove beneficial.  Early settlers in many places were more outcasts/branching out for a new life rather than interested in extending the reach of their nation?

Comment: (In the end, with the wars in the colonies (French-Indian, American Revolution, 1812)... wonder if it did prove that lucrative/beneficial to the UK.  Then again, the effects of colonization and future actions translate further... would there have been a US in the World Wars, would they have that significant economic partnership today.  Long story short... it's all complicated.  But that's the whole point, it wasn't just like go to new world -> $profit.  They of course did what they saw as best benefiting themselves at the time, as did all.  But interested to read more input on those nuances!)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is a list with the major factors. This list focuses on the period Oct 1492 to April 1607 and is extracted from this [Timeline of Colonial America](https://www.historytimeline.com/list/colonial-america-timeline/). The timeline already contains links to sources and articles for each of the events.

[image: diagram showing periods and events relevant to the colonial America from 1670 to 1730]

#### Major Factors

1. **North America was (quite) populated**. Epidemics reached north quite late (Seneca Measles, the first big epidemic, hit 1590). The land was not "terra nullius", it was filled with people and **even somewhat cultivated** (expansion of agriculture was an ongoing process coming from the more developed south).
2. **North American populations were "late neolithic", with advanced weaponry** like the Eskimo bows. Inuit used these bows to wipe entire populations through the north of the continent, and by 1400 these bows were not restricted to the Arctic but had reached the Plains and Northwestern Indians, but not further south. This is VERY different from mode 5 palaeolithic hunters in Australia.
3. **France and Spain were already trying hard to colonize the northern coast**, with violent episodes like the Matanzas Inlet Massacre.
4. **Up to 1550 finding a route to Asia was still the priority** for explorers. So was the priority for giving funding to expeditions by the English monarchy.
5. **The English were investing heavily in the colonization of Ireland already**, and this was true up to 1700 (see Cromwell). This also explains why the first American colonies were *not* a priority for England in particular.
6. **England had no naval superiority until autumn 1580** (Spanish Armada), and even after that, England only had slight advantage up to 1610. During that period, **privateering** was the focus. This tells you well about the state of affairs and English capabilities.
7. **International treaties**: Tordesillas, Alcaçovas... a series of treatises with the pope's approval to ensure dominance of Portugal and Spain in the New World. Spain back then controlled most of Italy, so the pope had not much of a choice.
8. **Internal English factors such as population growth**: in England growth happened after 1600, first Enclosure Act is 1604. So, there was simply no internal demographic push.

#### Minor Factors

9. **Indian tribes had guns starting 1540**, thanks to first fur trading explorers.
10. **Commercial Agriculture** like cotton, rice, tobacco was developed later in North American than in Central America and Caribbean. So, there were less economic incentives.
11. **Colonization law framework**: the Spanish and Portuguese had laws about the acquisition of new territories. People knew what to expect. These were used in the Reconquista and later in America. England did not have laws like these, but I'm not an expert on the topic. The Headright system start date is very late (1618).

I'm sure there are some more minor factors that would be nice to include.

Comment: Good answer, but you forgot a major point. At the time ships didn't have a lot of space to store fresh water and other supplies, having ports along the route to resupply was vital. Newfoundland might be good, but the northern routes in winter were dangerous. The Azores and the Canary islands provided useful stopovers.

Comment: Referencing external material is acceptable, but this leads to a commercial enterprise where _I do not get_ the ref's you insinuate here. 24.5$/year and _the ad_ vaguekly says/promises it'd be 90% Wikipedia-based _&_ 75% Britannica 'based'. Nothing to follow up? So, in terms of 'refs for an answer' here, I'd say I see no actual ref at all.

Comment: As a footnote. Do you have any sources on the bow and its influence on the demographics of pre columbian America?

Comment: @FluidCode Perhaps you can explain (going from the most important "major factor 1" why it took England longer than Spain when the North was densely populated—but 'Spain's' (South) America was _even denser_ populated/"more developed", yet Spain was supposedly 'faster'? Eitehr existing population & its structures are a factor in one direction or they are not. That factor seems not overly conclusive to anything?

Comment: "Do you have any sources on the bow and its influence on the demographics of pre columbian America?" Yes, start by learning about the Artic Small Tradition, papers like "Bow and Arrow in Northern North America" by Maschner and Mason.

Comment: "why it took England longer than Spain when the North was densely populated—but 'Spain's' (South) America was even denser populated/"more developed" **The more populated south and central America had state and state-like "advanced" societies, so if colonizers topple the elite, they then can get to control the power structures already in place**. This was not possible in North America, because there were no such state-like power structures.

Comment: This timeline is really great (the other timelines there are super fun as well). I wish its resolution were a bit better and that it was free for download :) If anyone's aware of something of similar quality (content-wise), please share.

Comment: Re "*England had no naval superiority until autumn 1580 (Spanish Armada), and even after that, England only had slight advantage up to 1610.*": Over whom? The [Dutch admirals](http://thedutchgoldenage.nl/people/navy.html) de Ruyter, Tromp elder and junior, Drakenburgh, Hein, de With, and others, enjoyed superiority over the Royal Navy well into the 17th century, with de Ruyter burning, pillaging, and looting the entire English fleet in [the Medway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raid_on_the_Medway) in 1657.

Answer (score 6):

> It took over 100 years after the New World's discovery for other European powers, but particular to this question, Britain, to attempt likewise, by which time many resource-rich regions were already claimed by Spain and Portugal.

Columbus landed in the Bahamas in 1492, and returned to Europe in March, 1493.

Sir Francis Drake claimed New Albion for England in 1579.

> On 5 June 1579, the ship briefly made first landfall at what is now South Cove, Cape Arago, just south of Coos Bay, Oregon, and then sailed south while searching for a suitable harbour to repair his ailing ship. On 17 June, Drake and his crew found a protected cove when they landed on the Pacific coast of what is now Northern California. While ashore, he claimed the area for Queen Elizabeth I as Nova Albion or New Albion.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Drake#Coast_of_California:*Nova_Albion*(1579)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Drake#Coast_of_California:_Nova_Albion_(1579))

Sir Humphrey Gilbert claimed St. John's, Newfoundland, in 1583.

The first colony on Roanoke in North Carolina lasted from 1585-1586.  The second Roanoke colony was founded in 1587 but had disappeared by 1590.

So English claims and actual attempts at colonization in the Americas actually began less than a century after 1492/93.

I note that Spain and Portugal claimed all of the Americans between them, and were quite powerful countries during that time.  So establishing permanent English, French, Dutch, etc. settlements in the Americas would be creating settlements with locations which would eventually become known to the rightful rulers of those lands and then be in danger of being attacked and destroyed as punishment for such illegal trespassing.

Comment: I think that last paragraph may be worth investigating (I haven't done so at this point). Given the [papal bull of 1493](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter_caetera), anyone else trying to take over land in the New World was arguably defying the Pope. England was still Catholic until 1532, and there were hopes of reconciliation upon the death of Henry, which didn't happen until 1547.

Comment: yeah that's a very good point actually, I'll look into that more

Comment: This is fairly unpersuasive. Is there any evidence that the English feared Hispanic retribution if they colonized the northern Atlantic coast of NA? It seems more likely that they simply didn't have far-flung conquest and expansion in their sights during most of the 1500s. (It was easier to sent p/i/r/a/t/e/ s/h/i/p/s/ privateers to pick off gold the Spanish had conveniently already gathered.)

Comment: @MarkOlson - Well, I'm thinking more specifically they likely weren't too keen on defying the Pope, but yes backed by Iberian sea power. Its also a fact that they didn't have much of a Navy before Henry VIII, but I suspect if I looked into why Henry  built a Navy, we'd find that's at least partially related to his defying of Papal authority (again backed by Iberian sea power). What happened to his daughter Elizabeth with the Spanish Armada shows the kind of danger he'd put England in.

Comment: @T.E.D. I'm reasonably familiar with the Tudor period and I don't think the Pope had much to do with it -- before H8's split, the Pope was glad to have him as a staunch anti-Lutheran. And after his reform of the nation's wealth, H8 didn't care. I also don't recall *any* mention that the Spanish cared one way or the other about NA north of Florida. I think the answer may be that England just was poorer and running behind in its development.

Comment: @MarkOlson - I'll certainly bow to expertise in the matter. I only know little bits. Oddly for instance, he was apparently a staunch anti-Lutheran *after* the split too. His main doctrinal disagreement with the Pope being the bit where he (Henry) couldn't personally do whatever he wanted.

Comment: Also the affairs **within** England plays a role. As your summery shows, only after most of the internal problems had settled down (around 1570), did Queen Elizabeth I start a more aggressive policy towards Spain.

Comment: @T.E.D.: However much ghost-writing assistance Thomas More provided, Henry did still get awarded *Defender of the Faith* for his [published rebuttal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defence_of_the_Seven_Sacraments) of Lutheranism. There's a reason the Anglican Church has always regarded itself as part of the *catholic* - ie *universal* - church.

Comment: That's an odd use of the phrase "rightful rulers".

Comment: Spain and Portugal had papal bulls for the line between their territories., but moved the border in the Treaty of Tordisillas in 1494, and no doubt madethat known to other European countries.

Answer (score 6):

When Spain accidentally found the new world, they did not have just an extensive experience in conquest, strategy and dealing with other cultures they adopted a very radical different approach compared to French and England:

- Spain and Portugal has en extensive experience in fighting, reconquering, evangelizing and dealing with a foreign culture: it took many centuries to push back all of the Moors/Arabs from the Iberian peninsula during the reconquista. Now it is hard to imagine, but back then Spain and Portugal were both the world's strongest superpowers back then. until England and France surpassed them some centuries later.
- After the conquest of a territory, all natives would be evangelized and converted to Christianity, making them subjects to the monarchy and treated as equals at the oversees provinces (see [Ley de Indias in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_of_the_Indies))
- Coming from a background the multiracial of Roman Empire and having been invaded several times by Germanic tribes, Arabs etc, they had no issue mixing themselves with other races ([see Mestizage in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscegenation), be aware that the article in English for Miscegenation doesn't honor enough the largest racial mixture ever produced, during the Spanish Empire). As difference the French and English suffered from common Central European ethnocentrism (nowadays would be known as racism), and fought and exterminated natives when they could. A an example of such brutally difference, centuries later Thomas Jefferson sold his own son with a native as slave without any recognition.

This last point became extremely important as conquistadors often married nobility of the natives, normalizing social equality between both groups of people (social differences depended on being a servant or having a royal title rather than race), and American royal societies were invited to take part in Spain's Court and have some power oversees.

That fact alone made Spaniards and much more effective in building a multiracial empire with the help of the own natives who often wanted to defeat other tribes that oppressed them for centuries. For more information read about the conquest of Mexico and how many tribes joined barely 150 Spaniards marching against Tenochtitlan (1 million inhabitants) and how Hernan Cortes sons became the first Mexican and a full right citizen.

If I had to summarize: Spain built a generative Empire, whereas England only tried to build predatory empires, and needed quite a long time to advance socially, military and technologically to achieve that since built its colonies in America, first with Catholic slaves (mostly Irish) and then with African slaves to replace natives, whereas Spain built upon the existing societies.

These points are often missed in Anglo-Saxon countries, since the study of historical empires which is somehow felt as if it was the same "current country", this for sure is felt as part of politics or social identity of societies, and often military and strategical decisions of the past conflict with the present society. There is more information of that phenomenon on the [Black legend article at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Legend_%28Spain%29) which became a common tale during English Second empire, and after the repeated failures of France in America.

Related topics of interest, can be found in the Wikipedia articles:

- [Mexican Nobility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_nobility)
- Direct descendants of Moctezuma currently alive in Spain ([some general information here](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-descendants-of-Moctezuma))
- And the same for Atahulpa and other pre-Colombinan societies, remarkably [Queen Máxima of the Netherlands](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1xima_de_los_Pa%C3%ADses_Bajos) descends from Inca royalty, but without any relevance nowadays regarding history or geopolitics.

---- Edit for all the comments accusing me of lying or whatever -----

P.D. Some people on the comments accuse me to lie or something, please, first do not project self identity to historical facts from almost half millennia ago and check the sources by yourselves. Giving civil status to the natives was just a natural consequence of the long reconquista process were it happened already massively and thanks the Catholic mindset, thanks to the Catholic Queen Isabel and later thanks to the Pope who insisted on the fact that natives had soul. Therefore all them should be treated as innocent souls since they never heard the evangelic texts before, so a high paternalist attitude was pushed politically.

Also regarding racial-enslaving laws, that was not the case, check the first black person arriving to America (Juan Garrido) as free man and conquistador, the first black university professor in Europe (in Granada, Spain , XVI century) or the first interracial weddings, Catholic in the Spanish Florida. And still no utopia should be made, like all empires it condemned and restores slavery many times, and it took centuries to migrate from the mindset of ancient times to a more equal rights modern perspective, but that doesn't change the multi racial generative empire, like Romans, Ottomans or Russians. but not English, French or Dutch.

Just check the actual sources, everything Spain did was accurate, the letters from Cortes to the kings are preserved, also journals and reports were exhaustively kept preserving the Roman/Catholic tradition of documenting everything like we still do in the western world (and some other cultures).

With that I will stop editing to reply the comments, these were the reasons why some empires succeeded were others could not until some new advance in technology and military strategies were made. Nothing to do with competition of nowadays nations.

Comment: ?American royal society? (Thank you for the reply)

Comment: Check the wikipedia article for "Mexican nobility". The societies in America had already highly hierarchical society, not just Mexicas, also Inca Empire, etc These are largely documented, their descendants are in Spain (like Moctezuma descendants live current Spain, and many more).

Comment: Sorry, I am downvoting this answer. This is the typical apologia for the Spanish Empire that I see all the time on other sites (Quora en español and so forth), meaning that it is light on historical accuracy and heavy on rhetoric. Just to give an example that is fairly immaterial, it misrepresents the number of people that Cortés brought with him by a factor of four [(he seems to have had over 600)](https://iberoamericasocial.com/cortes-mexico/).

Comment: Much more importantly, it makes the claim that the natives of territories conquered by the Spanish Empire were "treated as equals." "More rights other empires, under ideal circumstances" might have been true, but definitely not equal. This manages to completely ignore  the fact that laws such as the Leyes de Burgos required that Indigenous inhabitants of Spanish territories be Christianized and that they work for the benefit of the Crown, often in encomiendas under the authority of Spanish colonists.

Comment: It definitely ignores the fact that such laws were only put in place *because* of the widespread mistreatment that was going on in Spanish colonies at the time, including enslaving some Indigenous people and even selling them in Spain. It was accounts like the "Brevísima relación de la destrucción de las Indias," detailing things that could very much not be considered equal treatment in Spanish colonies, that led to the reforms (of varying effectiveness) in the first place.

Comment: The answer also contrasts the British and French empires with the Spanish one, noting the existence of enslavement of Black people in British colonies, for instance. But besides ignoring the early slavery against Indigenous people in Spanish colonies, as already mentioned, it also fails to mention that there were [also some enslaved Africans and their descendants in some Spanish colonies until near the end of the 1800s.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavery_in_colonial_Spanish_America?wprov=sfla1)

Comment: A reasonable argument could probably be made that Britain and France were *more* brutal or *more* racist as colonial empires than Spain was, and the relative lack of intermarriage in British colonies versus Spanish ones is a historically interesting fact. But what's being argued here is that Spain was a "non-predatory" empire that treated Indigenous people in areas it colonized as equals and did not engage in innumerable harmful practices toward them, and that is simply not a historically defensible perspective.

Comment: guys If you self identify with ancient empires you will feel upset. These laws came as consequence of the Catholic Queen Isabel and later also the Pope insisting on the soul of the natives. There were no inherit racial-slavery laws, as matter of fact the first black person in America was a free man Juan Garrido, who took part of the conquest of Tenochtitlan, the first formal Nahuatl grammar dates from 1547 (almost on pair with english grammar  and even before french's one). Don't believe me, check the facts and do not self project current identity onto history: it's been almost half millennia

Comment: I ended up adding a Post Data for the comment, but that's my last edit, I usually do not discuss with nationalists, with you I made an exception since that's my first comment on SE history. Cross check the sources and historical documents, check the Spanish Black legend and why it was promoted. England wished to have arrived before to America and promoted legends and invented fantasy stories all the time. It just was not ready and still kept the little brother complex as it used to be during roman days as the a forgotten Roman province. Get it over, we are different folks already.

Comment: Sorry, it's a just a little surprising that you accuse the people who point out the historical inaccuracies in your answer of being nationalists when complaining about the so-called *leyenda negra* is a popular feature of *Spanish* nationalism.

Comment: You also seem to think that the commentators identify with historical empires. But then, what are we to call it when you respond to the fact that there were some enslaved Black people by pointing out that there were also some non-enslaved Black people? Like, to show the forward-thinking character of the Spanish Empire, you mention the presence of Juan Garrido, a Black conquistador, among Cortés's party. But you neglect to mention that Garrido himself was "rewarded" with enslaved Africans for his performance in the conquest, and that Cortés brought enslaved people with him on his expedition.

Comment: what I pointed out is that there were no racial slavery rules as a whole, just the common middle age class system, including servants (slaves) and I gave you several iconic examples of situations which you can fact check them. Whatever nationalists say, the actual history behind such things doesn't make the people nationalist, that would be a fallacy and you do not want to bring the conversation to that direction, don't you? As said, these were the reasons for which some empires flourish sooner in america.

Comment: When you say that there was just the "Middle Ages class system, including servants (slaves)" and there was nothing racial about it, that makes no sense historically. The Middle Ages were already over by the time of Cortés's conquest (they ended in 1500 at the *latest*). Servants and slaves were not the same: the first group had compensation and some degree of freedom to leave their jobs, the second did not. Enslaved people at the time of the initial Spanish colonization were very disproportionately from Africa or Indigenous, so of course race entered into it.

Comment: You seem to how heterogenous Euopean culture was, end even more across such a large empire which never became totally centralized, in spite of Borbon dynasty efforts. The natives were not enslaved for the exception of the ones captured in a war event, later that law was revoked to prevent abuses. And yes, they were servants free to move, but in the practice that was very rare any servant, in America nor in Europe. Look what Alexander von Humboldt said about Spanish American and how the natives who were servants were treated and compensated better than servants in Prussia and other powers.

Comment: And that's my last comment, I do not believe anyone in the internet, who is not exceptionally open minded, is capable of changing their opinion, no matter how many studies, testimonials or facts are brought. I gave you enough information, the works from Humboldt are scanned, published and translated in many languages (believe he wrote the original in French). Look the testimonials who actually travelled there at the time.

Is up to you to read more on the topic or continue insisting in the ancient politic propaganda that became a legend, but I won't stay here replying ad infinitum.

Answer (score 0):

England’s rulers were embroiled in internal politics whereas in 1492 Spain had just triumphantly and justifiably defeated the last of the Saracen entities in Iberia. They were on a roll.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Hist SE. Your answer would be greatly improved if you provided sources top back up your assertion. Thank you.

Comment: This answer should be expanded a lot. What were those internal political struggles in England during that time and why did they prohibit expansion to the Americas?

Answer (score -1):

During the revolutionary War 1775 – 1783, a strong presence of Britain was established in Quebec " to protect us from the rebel American fighing for independence." My people do not care but most of us and most of our land belong to the crown.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question as it pertains to a later period.